# Why does an extra line of space before \end{align} throw up an error?

Tags: equations, align

I often add extra spaces in my TeX file for readability, and I find this error cropping up whenever there is an empty line before `\end{align}`. What is the reason for the error and is there a way to alleviate this?

Comment: I'd recommend you start the line the blank lines with  a `%`. The reason is that that is how `align` is defined.

Comment: Blank lines are not allowed in display math environments.