# can't display equation in equation mode

Tags: equations, quoting

I wrote equations and don't understand why some equations are displayed and others not. For example this equation can't be displayed

```
\begin{quote}
\begin{equation}
Sim_{Dice}=\frac{2\times a}{c_{1}+c_{2}}

\end{equation}
\end{quote}
```

and this equation is correctly displayed

```
\begin{quote}
\begin{equation}
I(X,Y)=\sum\limits_{x,y}P(x,y)\ log \ \frac{P(x,y)}{P(x)P(y)}
\end{equation}
\end{quote}
```

they are in the same document.

Comment: Blank lines (which are interpreted as `\par` by TeX) are not allowed in math-mode.

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10355/82917) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/328779/82917).